# Clone and update in groovy

Tags: javascript, groovy

In javascript there is an easy way to generate cloned object with some of the fields updated:

```
const person = {
  isHuman: false,
  name: "gabe"
};


const person2 = {
    ...person1,
    name: 'alice'
}
```

Is there a way to do something like in groovy without copying all the fields manually? I am writing testcases where I wanna generate data with one attribute changed at a time.

Comment: https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_map_elements

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks! but i was specifically looking for groovy objects

Comment: I... am not sure what you mean. Everything in Groovy is an object. Do you mean an instance of a class? The code equivalent to the JS in the question is precisely what spread-map does.

Comment: > Do you mean an instance of a class?
Yes I meant an instance of a class or a data POJO. Let me update the question with this detail as well

Answer (score 2):

Can you use `@Immutable(copyWith = true)`

```
@Immutable(copyWith = true)
class Person {
    String first, last
}

def tim   = new Person('tim', 'yates')
def alice = tim.copyWith(first:'alice')

assert tim.first   == 'tim'
assert alice.first == 'alice'
```

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/ImmutableBase.html#copyWith

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot make changes to the source class.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways this can be done.

One is to construct instances by spreading in a map, e.g., given:

```
class Person { String name; Boolean isHuman; }
```

An instance can be constructed using the same spread-map operator I linked to:

```
m1 = [ name: "Gabe", isHuman: true ]
p1 = new Person(*:m1)
println p1
// Person: Gabe, isHuman=true
```

This avoids actual work. An exception will be thrown if a map key isn't an instance property.

A utility method grabbing *(non-synthetic)* prop names from a class, and iterates while putting the name/value pairs into a map is also an option *(and affords a bit more safety)*:

```
def toMap(obj) {
  obj.class.declaredFields
    .findAll { !it.synthetic }
    .collectEntries { [(it.name): obj."$it.name" ] }
}
```

Now we can construct a "prototype" object, but override properties:

```
p2 = new Person(*:toMap(p1), name: "Alice")
println p2
// Person: Alice, isHuman=true
```

There are also libraries that do this type of work.

Depending on your *actual* usecase it may not be necessary to do anything other than passing a map, however (duck typing).

Comment: The above approaches dont work if the object has nested objects under it, but I used something similar. I ended up: 1) converting the object into json string 2) Convert it into groovy maps using JsonSlurper. 3) Used the spread operators to clone objects 4) Converted the map notation back to JSON 5) Converted the json into the object

Comment: The problem now is, its very easy to mistype properties while cloning and updating as we are just updating a map and it doesnt know about object properties

Comment: I didn't see anything in the question about nested instances/structures. Personally I'd say you're going about this in the wrong way--it sounds more like you want either data-driven tests or a data factory setup of some sort.